# Logout Error with Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial 8.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem with assert_select in the users_login_test in 8.3 of Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial.

This is the test:

```
test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
   get login_path
   post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
   assert is_logged_in?
   assert_redirected_to @user
   follow_redirect!
   assert_template 'users/show'
   assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
   assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
   assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
   delete logout_path
   assert_not is_logged_in?
   assert_redirected_to root_url
   follow_redirect!
   assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
   assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path, count: 0
   assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
end
```

When I run the test I get 1 failure:

```
FAIL["test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout",    
UsersLoginTest, 2016-01-20 09:51:41 +0000]
test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout#UsersLoginTest (1453283501.83s)
    Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/login"]", found 0..
    Expected 0 to be >= 1.
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:31:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

Here is my sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
 def new
 end
def create
 user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
 if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
   log_in user
   remember user
   redirect_to user
 else
   flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
   render 'new'
 end
 end      

 def destroy
   log_out
   redirect_to root_url
 end
 end
```

My sessions_controller has a destroy method that redirects to root_url.  I am not sure what the problem is but I know that my test fails and when I try to logout I am redirected to the main page but I am still logged in (in the corner I still have the links to my profile, settings and logout).

@Papouche Guinslyzinho you asked me to post views, helper and destroy controller:

View: header.html.rb

```
      <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="containter">
           <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
          <nav>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <%if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= ;link_to "Users", "#"%></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", "#" %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li> <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %> 
                </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <%else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
          <%end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Sessions_helper:

```
module SessionsHelper

  #logs in given user
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  #Remembers user in session
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  #returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
      elsif(user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  #returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def log_out
      session.delete(:user_id)
      @current_user = nil
  end


  #forgets a persistent session
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  #logs out the current user
  def 
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end


end
```

Sessions_controller: destroy

```
 def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your sessions_controller?

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to overload, not knowing what was needed,  but I will post it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing Section 8.3 of the Hartl tutorial, but it looks like you've started to work on the next section, [Remember Me](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-remember_me).  This is where you implement persistent sessions.

I can tell, because you have some 'remember' stuff in your code. For example:

```
def remember(user)
  user.remember
  cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

Your test is failing, because you probably have an active remember token cookie, but your `log_out` method doesn't 'forget' it.  Essentially, you've only half-completed Hartl's section; so tests are naturally failing (proof that tests work!)

If you continue along the tutorial, it will guide you through the process of forgetting this cookie when logging out.  Or, you can backtrack and remove the bits you put it after 8.3.  Either way, this test should then pass.

Comment: Yeah I think that's it, after adding  return false if 'remember_digest.nil?' everything started working out.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

first try to see if you have the login path in your routes

```
rake routes | grep 'login'
```

you should have thoses:

```
login GET    /login(.:format)          sessions#new
      POST   /login(.:format)          sessions#create
```

Then by your error:

```
Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/login"]", found 0..
```

This said that it cannot find a `<a href="/login"...>` in your html page. So fire up your rails server and go to your browser and verify  your page source to see if the link tag for login looks like this: `<a href="/login"...>`

[image]

Comment: OP already confirmed not seeing the Log In link in the browser: "am still logged in (in the corner I still have the links to my profile, settings and logout)."

Comment: Ok @dwenzel could you post your views (the part that you output your login logout information---navbar)

Comment: could you put the content of your Helper in the destroy function. `Session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil` and comment #log_out

Comment: could you also post the content of your `params` for the destroy controller

Comment: Ok I have posted those things.

Comment: could you also delete the cookie in your log_out helper `cookies.delete :user_id` ,  `cookies.delete :remember_token`  because they 've been created in `remember`

Comment: I'm probably like the other lazy programmers and skipped the last line **layouts/_header.html.erb** : `<li><%= link_to "Log in",  "#" %></li>` I didn't pay attention to the last chunk of the code. Needed to change to `<li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>`. This answer helped. Indeed as other said, proof the test is working XD